# How can I turn my UINavigationBar into UINavigationController (for use with this library)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) Library. It takes a`UINavigationController` as an argument. However, in my `ViewController` (which is presented as a modal), I create a `UINavigationBar` by myself.

```
    // Create the navigation bar
    navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44 + statusBarHeight()))
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "New Conversation"
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: COLORS.logo0,
        NSFontAttributeName: FONTS.title
    ]

    //Back Button
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateSessionViewController.backButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
    let cross = UIImage(named: "cross.png")
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xcccccc)
    backButton.setImage(cross?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    backButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems =  [backButtonBar]

    //Add nav bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

How can I pass this navigation bar to the library as an argument? This is what the library supports:

`MRNavigationBarProgressView(forNavigationController: UINavigationController!)`

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense, you could present modally a `UINavigationController` that wraps this `ViewController`.